# HTML Input: uploading multiple files maxes at 20

Tags: php, mysql, input, upload

I have an html input field, such as

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <h3>Files:</h3>
        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="image[]" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And I want the user to be able to upload multiple files at once. My php for this uses a `for` loop to cycle through all the files, gathers information on each one, and then uploads them one by one.

```
for($i = 0;$image['name'][$i] == true;$i++)
{
    //code
}
```

But this won't upload more than 20, ending with an error, `Notice: Undefined offset: 20 in F:\www\hdp\process.php on line 39`. Now, if I were to upload 5 images, it would give me `Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in F:\www\hdp\process.php on line 39`, but that would be ok because it would still upload all 5 photos (0,1,2,3,4). I need it to upload all the photos the user adds.
I know uploading lots of files at once could be a bad idea, but it is just the site admin, and it's a photography portfolio site. So he needs to be able to upload a lot of photos at once. And if it's important, they are being uploaded to a MySQL database.

Comment: ...please tell me you're not relying on register_globals.  You aren't, right?  ;_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the 'wont upload more than 20' part... what are you basing this on?  You're getting an error either way it seems.

Change your for loop to check for isset($image['name'][$i]) instead, and you will no longer get an error.

```
for($i = 0; isset($image['name'][$i]); $i++)
{
    //code
}
```

As mentioned by yes123, you risk hitting the maximum POST size and should check php.ini.

Comment: When I tell the input to select, say 60 files, it still exits at index 20.

Comment: run a var_dump on $image and see what you've got in the variable itself.

Comment: @DavidR I would recommend using another upload approach, like those found here:  http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=multiple+uploader+flash+php

Comment: Hm, var_dump shows it exiting at index 19 also. Then maybe it's something with the HTML? But when I select a large number of files it will say, "60 files" or "50 files" or however many I selected.

Comment: I've never used flash, but I feel like that might be the best answer for this. I'm not as familiar with php as I seem to need to be for this.

Comment: Well, believe it or not I am running into this problem, too, and I was just on a question page where another person is also experiencing this. My upload script (using CodeIgniter 3 and Ajax) is working excellently, except that when I open the browse files window, with 40+ jpg files, and I select them all, only 20--exactly 20--actually get uploaded.

Answer (score 11):

`max_file_uploads` in [php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) setting was the cause. Change it to what you want and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your php.ini settings for `post_max_size`

Also

```
upload_max_filesize  
memory_limit 
max_execution_time 
max_input_time
```

Comment: Used `ini_set()` for each of those, still exiting at 20.

Comment: you can't use ini_set. Put them in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Fosco's solution, but works differently (uses sizeof and a int to int comparison instead of an isset)

Neither this nor his are necessarily any better, just different ways to tackle the problem.

```
for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($image['name']); $i < $size; $i++)
{
    //code
}
```

And no, it doesn't run `sizeof()` each iteration.  That's an easy way to screw over performance.